# how to draw multiple rectangles

Tags: java, java-2d, paintcomponent

so I am trying to make a simple program where you click on the screen and it creates a block that falls and collides with a larger block beneath and sticks to it. Kind of like a simple collision program. The problem is when I create one block it deletes the block previously. I made an array, but it still does this. Do any of you know what Im doing wrong? Im sure its a simple fix.

```
    public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable {

public static JLabel statusbar; //displays a status bar showing what mouse movements are taking place
private Image cat;  //image of the cat
public int xCoord ; //get the coordinates of the mouse pressed
public int yCoord ;
public int xCreate;
public int yCreate;
public Rectangle Ground;
public Rectangle Block;
public boolean isClicked = false;
public int clickCount = 0;
Rectangle blocks[] = new Rectangle[10];

int blocknum = 0;

    public Screen(Frame frame) {
            loadPic(); //calls the loadPic method above 
                Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass(); //creates a new class to use the mouse motion listener
                    System.out.println("mouse works!");
         addMouseListener(handler);
         addMouseMotionListener(handler);
         statusbar = new JLabel("default");
            add(statusbar);
    }
    public void run(){ //this is the game run loop
        System.out.println("this is running");   
        try{
        } catch(Exception e) {} //exception handling

    }
    public void loadPic(){ //loads the picture from the other project but its the same pic
        cat = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Camtronius\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Moving Block Proj\\src\\MovingBlock\\catIcon1.png").getImage(); //gets the image
        System.out.println("Image Loaded!");
    }

     @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g); //paints the component, the picture, on top
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

             g2d.drawImage(cat, xCoord, yCoord, null);      

             g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
             Ground = new Rectangle(0,450,550,50);
             g2d.fillRect(0,450, 550, 50);

                 for(Rectangle blocknum : blocks){
                  if (blocks != null) {    
                      g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                       g2d.fillRect(xCreate,yCreate,50,50); 
                       System.out.println(blocknum);
                  }

                 }
                 //move();           
    }

   public void move(){   
    if(yCreate<400){
        yCreate+=1;
    }else{
        }
    if(Ground.intersects(blocks[blocknum])){ 
            yCreate=400;
            System.out.println("contains!");
        }
    }    
     private class Handlerclass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){

        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){

        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){

         if(blocknum<blocks.length){
            xCreate=event.getX();
            yCreate=event.getY(); 
            blocks[blocknum] = new Rectangle(50,50, xCreate, yCreate);
            repaint();
         }
        blocknum=blocknum+1;
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){

        } 
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){

        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){
           statusbar.setText(String.format("Coordinates are: %d, %d", event.getX(),event.getY()));
            xCoord=event.getX();
            yCoord=event.getY(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Painting is a destructive process.  That is, when a new paint cycle runs, the previous contents of the `Graphics` context should be cleared...

So, in you `paintComponent` method you are only painting the last block...

```
if(isClicked = true){
    blocks[blocknum] = new Rectangle(50,50, xCreate, yCreate);
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillRect(xCreate,yCreate,50,50);
    System.out.println(blocknum);
    repaint(); // THIS IS A BAD IDEA
}
```

DO NOT call any method that might cause `repaint` to be called.  This will put you in a potential cycle of death that will consume your CPU.

Instead, you should loop through the `blocks` array and paint each one...

```
for (Rectangle block : blocks) {
    if (block != null) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fill(block);
    }
}
```

And in you `mouseReleased` method, you should be adding the new rectangles...

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){
    blocknum=blocknum+1;
    if (blocknum < blocks.length) {
        xCreate=event.getX();
        yCreate=event.getY(); 
        blocks[blocknum] = new Rectangle(xCreate, yCreate, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you take a look at [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: I added the code you suggested and edited it above. It still only draws one block at a time though. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Opps, I a mistake in the `mouseReleased` code and have updated the `paintComponent` loop